# Is there a way to group steps in GitHub Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to conditionally execute several steps in a GitHub Actions job. Looking at the documentation, I found nothing of the sort. Did I overlook something, or is this just not possible?

Comment: Why not using a conditional expression at the job level, that will contain your several steps?

Comment: Say, it's a matrix build, which builds for x86 and x64, but if it's x86, it needs to take a different path. Since artifact sharing works terribly in GitHub, it's easier to continue using the environment that was created by the previous steps, rather than trying to recreate it from slooooooowly uploaded artifacts to another job.

Comment: If you use a matrix build, wouldn't it be possible to use something like `${{ matrix.build-type }}` in an `if` condition to check if it's `x86` or `x64` to execute the job / steps or not?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm doing already... of course.

Comment: In that case, I understand you are already conditionally executing several steps. For what I know, there is currently no option to optimize it another way...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group `runs` you can use [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action), but if you want to use custom aztion referenced via 'uses` it doesn't support yet. In this case your option is group them in the job and add condition at the job level.

Comment: I should've stated in my question that I've seen this  part of the documentation before, and that it isn't what I want. I don't want to implement custom actions (if I was doing that, I'd ditch all the GitHub markup nonsense altogether, not just this particular aspect). I was just wondering about the GitHub action definition language, which is so poorly documented that it's not possible to tell if a feature is present or not.